# Why isn't .text() returning the true value?

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't this show what the text is inside the object?

```
 <ul>
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
     <li>3</li>
 </ul>
```

jQuery:

```
   $("ul").append('<li class="hi">4</li>');
   alert( $(".hi").text );
```

Instead of showing the `.text()`, it shows some other js mumbo jumbo. What am I doing wrong here?

http://jsfiddle.net/hkGyG/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the parenthesis. Use

```
alert( $(".hi").text() );
```

You were simply alerting the function instead of calling it and alerting the result.